# How to get rid of annoying hover info in folder?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, gui, interface

In the attached picture the annoying hover info covers my file. I can't either do a right click or see the name. Only maximizing the window solves the issue, but can't do that cause I need the space for the rest of the windows.

Long story short... anyone knows how to get rid of these annoying hover infos?

[image]

Comment: Very interesting issue. Sadly, there is no way to do this without compiling your own version or using a different file manager.

Comment: Is this something that changed recently? Don't recall seeing it before recent times.

Comment: It is still quite a while, Ubuntu 12 and onwards ...

Comment: ehm when I do that the text is aligned to the right leaving a bit open to select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

At the moment there is no way to get rid of this extraordinarily annoying bug! This issue has been pottering along for several years, witness the following 2 inter-related  bug reports:

- [Launchpad 2011: Status Bar Covers File Name at Bottom](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/797485)
- [Gnome Bugzilla 2011: Tooltip display for last item makes item uneditable (when not using status bar)](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=651293)

You can see that the issue has not been resolved despite *5 years* since the original reports.

**Solution**

- Subscribe yourself to these 2 bug reports
- Add your own comments and insights to the reports
- Wait patiently :)

Comment: This bug is certified annoying.